# consecutive 1 in the array after using at most k 0's

Tags: java, algorithm

This is a modified version of the [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/max-consecutive-ones-iii/description/) task.

Given a binary array nums and an integer `k`, return the maximum number of consecutive `1's` in the array if you can flip `at most k 0's`.

Now I want to know the **possible ways** to get the maximum number of consecutive 1's

**Example:**

```
Input 1010101
K = 1
```

**Possible combinations are :**

```
1110101
1011101
1010111
```

So there are **3 possible ways** where maximum consecutive 1's (111) occurs for this input

**Constraints:**
length of input array is 1 to 10^5
size of k is 0 to array length

Solution to get the longest consecutive ones is:

```
 public int longestOnes(int[] A, int K) {
        int i = 0, j;
        for (j = 0; j < A.length; ++j) {
            if (A[j] == 0) K--;
            if (K < 0 && A[i++] == 0) K++;
        }
        return j - i;
    }
```

How to get the number of possible ways.

Comment: Assuming k > the count of zeros, go through all the combinations of k flips and see which ones create the maximum.  As a concrete example, if k = 3 and there are 5 zeros, then you check the 10 different flips.  00111, 01011, 01101, 01110, 10011, 10101, 10110, 11001, 11010, 11100.  There's a binary number pattern there you can use to your advantage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use two pointers. Advance the forward pointer whenever there are <= k zeroes between the pointers; advance the rear pointer otherwise.

Any time there are <= k zeroes between the pointers, you have a potential solution. Note its length (distance between pointers). If it is a new maximum then set the count that achieves this maximum to 1 and proceed. If it is the current maximum then increment the count of solutions which achieve this maximum by 1. If neither then just proceed through the array.

Example: I'll use || to represent the two pointers, considering anything between them

```
Input 1010101
K = 1
||1010101, len = 0, max = 0, count = 1
|1|010101, len = 1, max = 1, count = 1
|10|10101, len = 2, max = 2, count = 1
|101|0101, len = 3, max = 3, count = 1
|1010|101, invalid, max = 3, count = 1
1|010|101, invalid, max = 3, count = 1
10|10|101, len = 2, max = 3, count = 1
10|101|01, len = 3, max = 3, count = 2
10|1010|1, invalid, max = 3, count = 2
101|010|1, invalid, max = 3, count = 2
1010|10|1, len = 2, max = 3, count = 2
1010|101|, len = 3, max = 3, count = 3
```

linear time, constant space.

Comment: Very good! Bravo!

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to split the string by 0, then add 2 by 2 the blocks of 1s and get the max value. In c# ...

```
string[] b = Console.ReadLine().Split("0");
string[] t = b;
int r = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < t.Length-1; i++){
 int v = (t[i].Length + t[i+1].Length);
 r = v > r ? v : r;
}
Console.WriteLine(r+1);
```

Comment: can you explain this with an example